# setting values depending on the TD.id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a value to TD elements based on their id's. to do this i am trying to pass a range of id's through if statements, see below;

```
var pricing = 0;
var extraLeg = 9.99;
var standardSeat = 4.99;
var upFront = 9.99;
var extraLeg1 = 13.99;

  var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (var T = 0; T<tds.length; T++)
  {
    if(tds[T].id == "_1a","_1f")
    {
       pricing = extraLeg1;
    }
    if(tds[T].id == "_2a","_6f")
    {
       pricing = upFront;
    }
    if(tds[T].id == "_7a","_11f")
    {
       pricing = standardSeat;
    }
    if(tds[T].id == "_12a","_13f")
    {
       pricing = extraLeg;
    }
    if(tds[T].id == "_13a","_23f")
    {
       pricing = standardSeat;
    }     
  }
```

> each row of the table consists of 7 td elements; 
>  "_1a","_1b","_1c","aisle number","_1d","_1e","_1f"

However when I try this the first element that is clicked sets the price for all the other elements despite the for loop. can anyone advise me on how to fix this so that the td's are assigned the specific values?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? Also your if statements aren't valid. Finally, td elements can't have value attributes.

Comment: I should have specified in the question that the if statements are to check a range of TD.id , pricing is a value that is assigned to a text box if the TD.id is in that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing comparison incorrectly.

It should be like:

```
if(tds[T].id == "_13a" || tds[T].id == "_23f")
```

In your code, the expression `tds[T].id == "_13a","_23f"` evaluates to "_23f" due to the comma, and since it becomes truthy, all the if conditions get executed.

You can check this in console: `console.log((2 == 3, "_23f"));`

That said, you should consider using a Switch block for better presentation of the code and making future changes easier.

```
  var pricing = 0;
  var extraLeg = 9.99;
  var standardSeat = 4.99;
  var upFront = 9.99;
  var extraLeg1 = 13.99;

  var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (var T = 0; T<tds.length; T++)
  {
      switch (tds[T].id) {
          case "_1a":
          case "_1f":
              pricing = extraLeg1;
              break;
          case "_2a":
          case "_6f":
              pricing = upFront;
              break;
          case "_7a":
          case "_11f":
              pricing = standardSeat;
              break;
          case "_12a":
          case "_13f":
              pricing = extraLeg;
              break;
          case "_13a":
          case "_23f":
              pricing = standardSeat;
              break;
      }
  }
```

EDIT: If you wanted to add more like "_1b", "_1c" then you can club together the cases wherever your pricing is same. For example:

```
switch (tds[T].id) {
      case "_1a":
      case "_1b":
      case "_1c":
      case "_1d":
      case "_1e":
      case "_1f":
          pricing = extraLeg1;
          break;
      case "_2a":
      case "_6f":
          pricing = upFront;
          break;
      case "_12a":
      case "_13f":
          pricing = extraLeg;
          break;
      case "_7a":
      case "_11f":
      case "_13a":
      case "_23f":
          pricing = standardSeat;
          break;
  }
```

Comment: ok thanks, in the case of the switch blocks would i have to declare every td as a new case or is there away to set a range for this eg <br> "_1a","_1b","_1c","_1d","_1e","_1f" would all be one case?

Comment: Check my edit, and also go through http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp to know more about switch.

Comment: this is still giving me the same issue where all the td elements are set to the same price.

Comment: Have you added any code to set the pricing into the TD? This code stores the value in `pricing` variable, but you should have something like `tds[T].innerHTML = pricing;` after the switch block.

Comment: Great Thats Worked Thank you!

Comment: Wow you sure have a lot to study if you're going to be programming for a while! Go through the JS tutorials on w3schools, it helps a lot. Have a great day :-)

Comment: Yeah im new to javascript so still got a lot to learn. Thank you again for your help :)